# Rearranging a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

i have a table with 62 columns

something like

```
CREATE TABLE history_employees (
     id INT NOT NULL,
     first_name VARCHAR(20),
     last_name VARCHAR(20),
     hire_date DATE NOT NULL,
     job_code INT NOT NULL,
     dept_id INT NOT NULL,
     .
     .
     .
     .

);
```

now I want to change the order of the columns in order arrange data properly and to improve retrieval using select ( if the order in which columns are arranged and the order in the select list matches then there will  be some improvement in the query execution)

I don't want to use alter table....modify

Can anyone help me to do the above with single or few statements;

Comment: This is not going to make the query faster. Rather show us the query that is slow and then lets help you with that. I repeat what are you doing is not going to make a huge difference.

Comment: if you are using sqlyog there is a function right click on the table and use reorder columns

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to speed up a query that references a small number of columns you should use covering indexes: http://dom.as/2007/01/26/mysql-covering-index-performance/

Altering the column order will not improve performance because databases retrieve results one entire row at a time (as described in [ICP Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `EMS SQL Manager`, you can try this one. [Reordering Columns](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/manager/documentation/hs5433)